# handling uri schemes in android

Tags: android, uri

I have created a custom url scheme for my app.

```
 <intent-filter>               
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />               
 </intent-filter>
 <intent-filter>
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 <data android:scheme="myapp" />
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
 </intent-filter>
```

Right now, when my app is launched from another app, despite of whichever activity is in foreground, my app is launched with the main activity only.
Is there anyway to make sure my app launches in its last-left-state?
Or is there anyway that i will be notified before my app is launched?

Answer (score 0):

You should use getIntent.getData() and then act accordingly. For example if the data has /home or/user you could focus that view in the container.